# Have a list of lists with each element a tuple. Prob. specifying specific tuple element

Tags: python, distance, edit

```
def distances(a, b):
    """Calculate edit distance from a to b"""

    # declare matrix and set top left box to 0 and none
    cost = [[(0,0) for x in range(len(a)+1)] for y in range(len(b)+1)]
    cost[0][0] = (0, None)

    # fill in first row
    for i in range(1, len(a)+1):
        cost[i][0] = (i, Operation.DELETED)

    #fill in first column
    for j in range(1, len(b)+1):
        cost[0][j] = (j, Operation.INSERTED)

    # fill in rest of the table from left to right, one row at a time
    i = 1
    j = 1
    while i < len(a) + 1:
        while j < len(b) + 1:
            if a[i-1] == b[j-1]:
                cost[i][j] = (cost[i-1][j-1], Operation.SUBSTITUTED)
                j += 1
            else:
                subcost = min(cost[i-1][j][0], cost[i][j-1][0], cost[i-1][j-1][0])
                if subcost == cost[i-1][j][0]:
                    cost[i][j] = (cost[i-1][j][0] + 1, Operation.DELETED)
                    j += 1
                elif subcost == cost[i][j-1][0]:
                    cost[i][j] = (cost[i][j-1][0] + 1, Operation.INSERTED)
                    j += 1
                elif subcost == cost[i-1][j-1][0]:
                    cost[i][j] = (cost[i-1][j-1][0] + 1, Operation.SUBSTITUTED)
                    j += 1
        i += 1
        j = 1

    return cost
```

Gives me this error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

and specifies

```
subcost = min(cost[i-1][j][0], cost[i][j-1][0], cost[i-1][j-1][0])
```

as the problem line
Each `cost[i][j][0]` should be specifying the first element of the jth tuple in the ith list of cost, which should be an int, yet it's saying they're tuples and I don't get why.

Comment: `cost[i][j-1][0]` is a tuple on iteration 3. (`i = 2, j = 2, cost[2][1][0] is a tuple ` )

Comment: The problem is in `cost[i][j] = (cost[i-1][j-1], Operation.SUBSTITUTED)`.  You are producing a tuple whose first element is a tuple rather than an int; you need an extra `[0]` in there like in all the other cases.